# Perl - extract data from certain offsets in hex

Tags: perl, seek

ok i have actually put some effort into trying to accomplish this, this time :)

i have this code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

open(my $fin, '<', "./file1.bin") or die "Cannot open file1.bin: $!";
binmode($fin);
open(my $fout, '>>', "./file2.bin") or die "Cannot create file2.bin: $!";
binmode($fout);


seek($fin,0x760, SEEK_CUR);
read($fin, 0x400,)
print ("$fin, $fout);
close($fout);
```

i dont know if you can see what i am trying to do, but i am trying to seek to offset 0x760
then read from offset 0x760 then read a chunck of bytes(0x400) from file1.bin and print that chunck of bytes to file2.bin

so i guess this is the flow of what i am trying to do:

```
open file1.bin for reading in binmode
open file2.bin for writing in binmode
seek to offset 0x760 in file1.bin
read a chunk of data (0x400) from file1.bin
write the chunk of data (0x400) to file2.bin
```

hopefully you understand what i am trying to accomplish :) and any input would be educational :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your code:

```
print ("$fin, $fout);
```

should be replaced by (after the opening and bindmode)

```
my $buffer = '';
sysseek $fin, 0x760, SEEK_SET;
sysread $fin, $buffer, 0x400;
syswrite $fout, $buffer;
close $fin;
close $fout;
```

Comment: thanks man, this was burning my brain up, i been reading for 2 days now, and my OP was my best crack at it, lol

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to enable warnings (which would have told you "SEEK_CUR" is being interpreted as a string since you haven't imported the constant).

Read the documentation for read; you need to supply a variable for the data read to go into.

Also read up on print; its syntax is `print FILEHANDLE LIST`; (where FILEHANDLE would be $fout and LIST the variable you read into).

Comment: ok, i will read up on that definitely read up some more, it just that with all the information, and im new to it, it can easilt get miscontrued lol.